# Importing zexp from Plone4.3.* to Plone5.1rc failed

Tags: plone-4.x, plone-5.x

Import failed at http://127.0.0.1:8080/Plone/en/manage_importObject

What is this message mean?

How to add uid_catalog?

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 138, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 48, in call_object
  Module OFS.ObjectManager, line 627, in manage_importObject
  Module OFS.ObjectManager, line 649, in _importObjectFromFile
  Module Products.BTreeFolder2.BTreeFolder2, line 461, in _setObject
  Module zope.event, line 31, in notify
  Module zope.component.event, line 24, in dispatch
  Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.event, line 32, in objectEventNotify
  Module zope.component._api, line 136, in subscribers
  Module zope.component.registry, line 321, in subscribers
  Module zope.interface.adapter, line 585, in subscribers
  Module OFS.subscribers, line 110, in dispatchObjectMovedEvent
  Module OFS.subscribers, line 143, in callManageAfterAdd
  Module Products.Archetypes.BaseFolder, line 95, in manage_afterAdd
  Module Products.Archetypes.BaseObject, line 160, in manage_afterAdd
   - __traceback_info__: (<ATFolder at /Plone/en/news>, <ATFolder at /Plone/en/news>, <Folder at /Plone/en>)
  Module Products.Archetypes.Referenceable, line 242, in manage_afterAdd
  Module Products.Archetypes.Referenceable, line 212, in _updateCatalog
  Module Products.CMFCore.utils, line 13, in check_getToolByName
  Module Products.CMFCore.utils, line 120, in getToolByName
AttributeError: uid_catalog
```

Comment: For readers driving by: ZEXP-files are said to be avoided and only to be used for transfers between Plone-sites of same version. Very surprised it seemed to have worked for you amongst different major-versions even.

Comment: @ida-ebkes Thank you. I found reference page said cant import between different versions. `The data is a raw dump of Python internal data structures, which means that the source and the target Plone versions must be compatible. For example, a export from Plone 3 to Plone 4 is not possible.` https://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/content/importexport.html#zope-2-import-export

Answer (score 0):

Make uid_catalog yourself.

- Goto  http://127.0.0.1:8080/Plone/manage_main
- Choose Zcatalog from selectbox
- Push Add

[screen shot of manage_main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/perSF.png)